# Relation between singular homology and cohomology

Tags: ring-theory, homology-cohomology

Is it true that for every $\sigma \in H_k(X;R)$ there is a $\phi \in H^k(X;R)$ such that $\phi(\sigma) = 1$ for every topological space $X$ and ring with unity $R$ ?

That strikes me as a very nontrivial thing and I could not prove this by myself. Moreover, can we say that if $\sigma$ is a generator of $H_k(X;R)$ then $\phi$ is a generator of $H^k(X;R)$? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

It is not always true, suppose that $R=Z$. Then $H_k(X,Z)$ may have torsion.
In general, homology and cohomology are related by the universal coefficient theorem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem

Comment: What exactly goes wrong if there's torsion? And if there's no torsion, say the k-th homology or/and cohomology are free $\mathbb{Z}$ - modules or $R$ is a field, is it then true?

Comment: I just answered my own question: via the universal coefficient theorem the homology and cohomology are the same if there's no torsion.